# How to order on a calculated value without selecting it

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I want to order entities returned from a Doctrine query on a calculated scalar value. Something like this in simplified DQL:

```
SELECT a, SOMEFUNC(a.foo,a.bar) AS b 
FROM MyStuff:Thing a 
ORDER BY b
```

The ordering works, but I don't actually want the scalar value `b`, it's just for sorting; I only want `Thing` entities back.

However with this query each result returned would be an array with the root object I want at `[0]` and then the redundant scalar value at `[1]`. This makes perfect sense, but it's not what I want and I don't know how to ask Doctrine to ignore the value.

How is this kind of ordering supposed to be done with Doctrine? How do I perform this ordering without selecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AS HIDDEN` clause:

```
SELECT a, SOMEFUNC(a.foo,a.bar) AS HIDDEN b 
FROM MyStuff:Thing a 
ORDER BY b
```

Source : https://speakerdeck.com/asm89/what-is-new-in-doctrine?slide=19

Comment: Wonderful. But doesn't look like it's made it into Symfony yet (2.1.3)

Comment: what is your doctrine version ?

Comment: It should be available since doctrine 2.2 : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/AST/SelectExpression.php

Comment: Ah yes. I have version 2.3. the grammar in that code shows it should be `AS HIDDEN b`